# BadRequest 400 when mocking a resttemplate exchange method

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I am using mockito to test a resttemplate exchange method, but I am getting a `BadRequest 400 : "{"timestamp":"2022-06-09T20:27:37.950+00:00","status":400.` I am using junit 5 as well.

This is my code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import exception.HmacExeption;
import model.Payload;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.*;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class GithubWebHookServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private CarService carService;


   @Test
    public void test() throws HmacExeption, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, JsonProcessingException {
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<String>("sampleBodyString", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);

        Mockito.
                when(restTemplate.exchange(
                                Matchers.anyString(),
                                Matchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
                                Matchers.<HttpEntity<?>> any(),
                                Matchers.<Class<String>> any()
                        )
                ).thenReturn(responseEntity);

        carService.executeRestCall(new Payload());
    }

}
```

Not sure, what am I missing.

Thanks!!

Comment: Might be valuable to see the implementation of your CarService.

Comment: The error is related with the mock of the resttemplate object in the  when(restTemplate.exchange(... line

Comment: I reckon the `restTemplate.exchange(...)` call within the CarService is slightly different and therefor not matches the mock rule. That's why I'm asking for it.